# VSCode Prettier and vue confusing formatting

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, prettier

With this code

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar app color="brown darken-4" dark>
    <v-btn color="brown lighten-3" class="hidden-sm-and-down">REGISTRIEREN</v-btn>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

Prettier suggests this:

```
  3:62  warning  Replace `>REGISTRIEREN</v-btn` with `⏎······>REGISTRIEREN</v-btn⏎····`  prettier/prettier
```

But the code than would look like this:

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar app color="brown darken-4" dark>
    <v-btn color="brown lighten-3" class="hidden-sm-and-down"
      >REGISTRIEREN</v-btn
    >
  </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

Where prettier does not complain. Is this expected behaviour or a bug in VSCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is expected behaviour.
Prettier does a line break after 80 characters or so. And it breaks before the `>` because if it breaks after, it actually adds a white space, so you might run into display issues later on.

this is correct:

```
 <v-btn color="brown lighten-3" class="hidden-sm-and-down"
   >REGISTRIEREN</v-btn
 >
```

this is not (the line break before and after 'REGISTRIEREN' is an actual character):

```
<v-btn color="brown lighten-3" class="hidden-sm-and-down">
   REGISTRIEREN
</v-btn>
```

You can customise some of these rules, but I honestly recommend just keeping what comes out of the box - the more you customise, the more things keep breaking during updates etc.

Comment: This behavior of Prettier is also explained here: https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting

Comment: Thanks for the link @thorn̈. I was aware of "significant" white space but thought it a thing of the dark (xhtml/html 4) ages.